# Can I move a single element of a QObject array to another QThread

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, qt, qthread

So I was trying to write a qt application that would require a variable number of threads. I was going to use the method I've used for threads before where I create a class and then use the moveToThread function on that object. But this time I would have an array of QObjects and I would be moving each one to a separate thread.

My question is: Would sending an element from that array to live in a different thread break the array, or would it still operate normally? I just don't know if moving an object to another thread actually moves around memory.

For the record, at someone else's suggestion I found a way to make the application using just 2 threads instead of a variable number. But I would still like to know how this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Move a QObject to a different thread doesn't move around memory in any way. So no, I won't break your array.

What moving a QObject to a different thread does is that it changes its *thread affinity*. The main effect concerns event handling - events sent to the object are processed by the event loop of the object's thread. If the object's thread isn't running an event loop, it won't get any events.

Note that the complete QObject tree created via parent/child relationship needs to live in the same thread.
In addition, the object needs to be deleted from the object's thread.

Back to your array: Your array won't be broken by moving its QObjects into another thread - however, you have to be very careful if you actually want to access any QObject in your array from the main thread - you need proper locking and mutexes to prevent race conditions, as QObject is not thread-safe.

So the array itself is fine, but you can't actually use the QObjects in it without proper locking.

Answer (score 1):

It won't break the array, as there's no memory movement involved. But moving a QObject to another thread makes the other thread responsibile for its deletion (QObject is reentrant, **not thread-safe**!), so don't attempt to delete the objects in that array by `qDeleteAll` or similar means from the "main" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the design pattern for Qt is to have the objects that do the work in the threads they are supposed to be doing the work in, and then communicate with them / each-other using signals/slots, which are thread safe. I would argue that you should "try to avoid" communicating with your workers directly via e.g. an array.

However, as others have said, doing so should not break the array - although, as others have mentioned, just don't try deleting the object (for more information: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html).